# Why do we have to take the real part in when solving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + x + 1}\ dx$ (Contour integral)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Here is an example from Priestley's Complex Analysis textbook ($\Gamma_R$ is arc of semi-circle sitting on real axis centered at 0):

[image]

She is stating that to evaluate the given integral, we must equate real and imaginary parts in the following equation:

$$ \int_{-R}^R f(x) dx + \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) dz = 2\pi i\  \mathrm{res}(f(z); \omega)$$

However, the LHS of the equation is equal to the RHS, and as $R \to \infty$, the second integral in the LHS goes to 0. The remaining integral on the LHS is real – so shouldn't the RHS automatically be real? Why is there a need to explicitly take the real part? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The remaining integral on the LHS isn't real.  $f(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix}}{x^2 + x  +1} = \dfrac{\cos x + i\sin x}{x^2 + x + 1} = \dfrac{\cos x}{x^2+x+1} + i\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2 + x + 1} \notin \Bbb R$.  Note also that the RHS isn't real.  It was explicitly given earlier and can easily be seen to be not real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the real part because $\mathrm{Re}[f(x)]$, not $f(x)$, is the function you want to integrate. Remember that $f(x)$ was $\frac{e^{ix}}{x^2 + x + 1}.$

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks